# Changing the color of a clicked table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

How can I, using jQuery,

Change the background color of the selected row in my table (for this example, let's use the the css class "highlighted"

and if the same row is clicked on again, change it back to its default color (white) select the css class "nonhighlighted"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

.highlighted {
    background: red;
}
.nonhighlighted {
    background: white;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Start here: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Have you made any effort on your own to this regard. Like using a selector and a click event?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
.highlight { background-color: red; }
```

If you want multiple selections

```
$("#data tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

If you want only 1 row in the table to be selected at a time

```
$("#data tr").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
    $("#data tr").removeClass("highlight");
    if(!selected)
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Also note your TABLE tag has 2 ID attributes, you can't do that.

Comment: I have a table and for each row, check Due Date column and if it is past today's date make that row font color red. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 11):

Create a css class that applies the row color, and use jQuery to toggle the class on/off:

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#data tr').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

The first click will add the class (making the background color blue), and the next click will remove the class, reverting it to whatever it was before. Repeat!

In terms of the two CSS classes you already have, I would change the `.nonhighlighted` class to apply to all rows of the table by default, then toggle the `.highlighted` on and off:

```
<style type="text/css">

.highlighted {
    background: red;
}

#data tr {
    background: white;
}

</style>

$('#data tr').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

Comment: This is selecting the `td`, it should be selecting the `tr` right?

Comment: Err yes! Thank you keen spotter of my lazy typing!

Comment: I would suggest $("#data tr") instead, in case there are other tables on the same page.

Comment: Updated the answer. Good quality control gang!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible solution that will color the entire row for your table.

CSS

```
tr.highlighted td {
    background: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#data tr').click(function(e) {
    $('#data tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jrthib/HVw7E/2/

Comment: how do you get it to unhilight the last selected row and to change the row color of the newly selected row?

Comment: I updated the code. You would have to remove the class on all rows, then add it to the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

in your css:

```
.selected{
    background: #F00;
}
```

in the jquery:

```
$("#data tr").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Basically you create a class and adds/removes it from the selected row.

Btw you could have shown more effort, there's no css or jquery/js at all in your code xD

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in JQuery but I have the same scenario and I able to accomplis like this:

```
$("#data tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected"); 
});
```

Style:

```
<style type="text/css">

.selected {
    background: red;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery :

```
$("#data td").toggle(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','blue')
},function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','ur_default_color')
});
```

Comment: only highlights the selected cell, does not unhilight last selected row, when a new row is selected

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second id declaration of table:

```
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500" **id="table1"**>
```

Answer (score 0):

.highlight
    {
         background-color: papayawhip;
    }

```
$("#table tr").click(function() {    
 $("#table tr").removeClass("highlight");
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set background-color

```
.highlight { background-color: red; }
```

for selecting just one row

```
 $("#Table_Id tr").click(function () {
        $("#Table_Id tr").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });
```

for selecting multi rows

```
 $("#Table_Id tr").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

To change color of a cell:

```
$(document).on('click', '#table tbody td', function (event) {


    var selected = $(this).hasClass("obstacle");
    $("#table tbody td").removeClass("obstacle");
    if (!selected)
        $(this).addClass("obstacle");

});
```