# Change color clicked row in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How can I change color of a clicked row of a Datatable?

I have my data table and a JavaScript to do some operations with the data of a clicked row:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
   var data = table.row( this ).data();
   // below some operations with the data
   // How can I set the row color as red?
} );
```

Thanks

Comment: Define a CSS class with the color that you want to use and add the class like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703978/3825777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the relevance of DataTable in this case but you can do this with jQuery.

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/ccd10f785e6b6d9e2c2b2503b219eab4

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
$('#myTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
   var data = table.row( this ).data();
   // below some operations with the data
   // How can I set the row color as red?
  $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

If you want to remove the highlight following pagination then I would suggest using one of DataTables custom events...

```
$('#myTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
  $(this).find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw